# I am trying to generate .h file in android-studio for NDK

Tags: android-ndk, android-studio-2.2, javah

Can anyone figure out whats the issue in this command.

i used command for generating is:

```
-classpath $Classpath$ -v -jni $FileClass$
```

it throws exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid class name: Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program
at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:129)
at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:107)
at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:64)
at com.sun.tools.javah.JavahTask.run(JavahTask.java:503)
at com.sun.tools.javah.JavahTask.run(JavahTask.java:329)
at com.sun.tools.javah.Main.main(Main.java:46)
```

MyNDK.class:

```
public class MyNDK {

// Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
static {
    System.loadLibrary("MyLibrary");
}

public native int getHelloSum(int[] val,int size);

}
```

Setting for NDK:
[image: NDK SETTING]

Comment: Try to put classpayh in quotes, `"&Classpath&"`

Comment: If you already have java class code, and inside android studio, could you use the missingFunctionInspection thing inside Android Studio to let it generate the prototype for you? it is a bit trick to use, but it might save some  trouble. One example is inside this: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-jni/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#3
it used gradle-experimental, but that particular step works for CMake/Ndkbuild too [ no change ].  It should do most of the work for your function,  one minor modification is to add extern "C" for hosting cpp file

Comment: @AlexCohn in place of $ i have used & with quotes now i am getting this error 
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\javah.exe" -classpath &Classpath& -v -jni com.myndkapp.MyNDK
Error: Could not find class file for 'com.myndkapp.MyNDK'.

Comment: My fault; it should be `$`

Comment: Yes it worked @AlexCohn Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Alex Cohn helped me to fix this the correct answer is :

```
-classpath "$Classpath$" -v -jni $FileClass$
```